# Remove first word if a sentence from pandas data frame column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
df:
col1      col2
 A        blue berry
 B        nice water bottle
```

I want to remove first word from the col2 values, the final data frame will look like this:

```
df1:
col1       col2
 A         berry
 B         water bottle
```

How to do this in most effective way using pandas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by first whitespace with `n=1` and then select second lists by indexing:

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.split(n=1).str[1]
print (df)
  col1          col2
0    A         berry
1    B  water bottle
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['col2'].str.split(n=1))
0           [blue, berry]
1    [nice, water bottle]
Name: col2, dtype: object
```

If performance is important and no missing values convert solution to list comprehension:

```
df['col2'] = [x.split(maxsplit=1)[1] for x in df['col2']]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
d['col2'] = d['col2'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.split(' ')[1:]))
```

Output

```
  col1          col2
0    A         berry
1    B  water bottle
```

Answer (score 1):

in your case

```
df1.col2 = df1.col2.str.split(" ",1).str[1]
```

might do the trick. 
The `.str`  gives you vectorised string functionality on columns and and split takes an additional argument which says how often it will maximaly split.